# Error when trying to import ActionBarSherlock Sample Project

Tags: android

[image]When I import the ActionBarSherlock Sample Project I get error saying  [SampleList] Unable to resolve target 'android-14'.  What could it be.please help

Comment: [GOOGLE](https://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=unable+to+resolve+target+%27android-14%27+actionbarsherlock&oq=Unable+to+resolve+target+%27android-14%27&gs_l=hp.1.2.0l4.1130815.1130815.3.1134340.1.1.0.0.0.0.456.456.4-1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.11.psy-ab.0RdTozWIvbo&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45921128,d.bmk&fp=15f8fc42242115e6&biw=1375&bih=812)

Answer (score 3):

Start `Android SDK Manager` and update downloading `Android 4.0 (API 14)`.

Or

Change the Project Properties to compile with an existing Android OS Version.

(Right click to your project folder > `Properties` > `Android` > select any version you want)

Comment: thanks for your comments. please see the image I have attached.

Comment: At the library at the "X" icon you need to remove the existing project and then "Add..." the workspace project of `Sherlock Library`. Both projects (library, samples) need to be opened in the workspace and connected for the app to run!

Answer (score 0):

ok,atlast managed to solve this issue. the problem was solved by importing the demo project in my eclipse workspace.for some reason eclipse did not like me to run the sample app from the actual folder. so you need to import the demo folder in ../JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-071a61c\actionbarsherlock-samples\demos and in eclipse while importing check the "copy files to workspace"